# How to test HTML elements added after a call is made?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

I have this piece of HTML (index.html):

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="users">

  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

The script fills the table when the app is started, by doing an API call and adding to the `tbody` element:

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="#" data-id="${user.id}" class="deleteUser">Delete</a></td>
  <td>${user.id}</td>
  <td>${user.firstName}</td>
  <td>${user.lastName}</td>
  <td>${user.email}</td>
</tr>
```

What I don't know how to do is:
 How I test the rows that has been added? Because, if I do:

```
it('should have at least three rows', (done) => {
    const index = fs.readFileSync('./src/index.html', "utf-8");
    jsdom.env(index, function(err, window) {
      const tbody = window.document.getElementById('users');
      console.log("LOG:" , tbody.children.length);
      expect(tbody.children.length).to.gte(3);
      done();
      window.close();
    });
  });
```

The log shows 0 due that in the html file, the `tbody` element has no child.

How should I test the resultant DOM? How do I should test the `tbody` element **after** is filled?

Comment: When is the API call made?

Comment: Where is `<tbody>` filled? Client-side or server-side?

Comment: Immediately at the app start, the index.js's first line is the call, and add it to the <tbody>

Comment: @Rodrigo.A92 So client-side then? In that case you need server-side rendering before the chai check.